# Why the same mysql sql with two result about icp between 5.6 and 5.7

Tags: mysql, innodb

Table

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `emp_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `birth_date` date NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `gender` enum('M','F') NOT NULL,
  `hire_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`),
  KEY `fnln` (`first_name`,`last_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

sql

```
explain select * from employees where first_name='Anneke' and last_name='Porenta';
```

5.6 result
[5.6 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OMdv.png)

5.7 result
[5.7 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZwP9.png)

Comment: Suggest you allow for longer names.

Comment: Get `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` to get more insight into the details.  8.0 is also missing "Using index condition" for this simple test case; I have seen it in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, not only is it to be expected, that a newer version of a database product may create different output for the query plan, it is also what you want: You want improvements to show up.

Now: The gist of the query plan is 100% identical: All columns, that existed in 5.6 show up identically in 5.7 - so the query plan itself has not changed.

What has changed is, that the newer version shows two more columns - since support for parallell querying of different partitions is new in 5.7 the `partitions column` is easily explained.

The `filtered` column stems from optimizations in the query planner: Obviously the selectivity of a conditionis very important for the query plan, and obviously the exact selectivity is not known before the query runs, but the newerquery planner informs you, which guestimates it uses. This is a good thing.

Comment: thank you, but  I want to know why extra is different. Whether the second result uses icp optimization?

Comment: The "Using index condition" is redundant - `key=fnln` and `ref=const,const` already include this information, so it is just a textual cleanup. I assume this is because a lot of possible "Extra" information came with the PQ feature.

Comment: When I run the different sql `explain select * from employees where first_name='Anneke' and last_name like '%Porenta%'` in 5.7, the extra column will display "Using index condition"

Comment: Of course! In this case the second condition is NOT subsumized, as it is not a perfect match but a range.

Comment: @EugenRieck - There is no parallel querying, even in 8.0.  The partitions column lists the result of "partition pruning".  The column existed in 5.6, but you had to ask for it.